# treating an array as a single variable

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, operators

code 1:

```
   .
   .
int main()
{
    char ch1[3];
    ch1[0]=ch1[1] = NULL;
    ch1[2]=0x01;
    ch1[2] = ch1[2]<<2;
    printf("%u", ch1[2]);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
     .
     .
```

the output of code:1 is 4 (as expected).

code 2:

```
    .
    .
int main()
{
    char ch1[3];
    ch1[0]=ch1[1] = NULL;
    ch1[2]=0x01;
    *ch1 = *ch1<<2;
    printf("%u", ch1[2]);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
      .
      .
```

but the output of code:2 is 1 as not expected! in line 6 of code:2, the modification done was changing `ch1[2] = ch1[2]<<2;` to  `*ch1 = *ch1<<2;`. I have tried treating the char array as one numerical value and have done the `<<` operation; I believe that my method is incorrect. is there any correct method to treat an array as a single numerical value to do basic mathematical operations?

## Update 1:

I have changed my code to the following:

```
int main()
{
    char ch1[3];
    ch1[0]=ch1[1] = NULL;
    ch1[2]=0x01;
    *(ch1+2) = *(ch1+2)<<9;
    printf("%u", ch1[1]);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

now I get the output:0. shouldn't I be getting the output 2 (i.e. 2^(9-8))? still, how to treat an array as a single numerical value?

right; but my actual question is if its possible to treat an array as a single value or not; that is by considering ch1[0], ch1[1], ch1[2] as a single block of memory of 24 bits.

Comment: using `*ch1` is the same as saying `ch1[0]`.

Comment: No, you will have to iterate over each element.

Comment: In your second method, you should use `*(ch1 + 2)` to bring it in line with the first one.

Comment: Are you trying to shift bits across character boundaries?

Comment: You don't know what `<<` does. Read about c operators.

Comment: `NULL` is a null *pointer* constant, not a null character. Change `ch1[0]=ch1[1] = NULL;` to `ch1[0]=ch1[1] = '\0';`

Comment: Is `NULL` no longer defined to be `0`? When did that happen? Granted, semantically it's misleading - you should use `0`. But as far as the compiler is concerned they should be the same.

Comment: I believe a<<b shifts the base-2 digits of a towards left.

Comment: @TomZych: `NULL` may be defined as `0`, as `((void*)0`, or in a variety of other ways. It expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant. Using it in a context requiring a character or integer value might happen to work on some implementations, but it's horrible style.

Comment: @user3633270 that is correct. What is *not* correct is your assumption that shift will carry through to the prior element in the array. That isn't how the language works.

Comment: *(ch1+2)<<9 ; shouldn't it shift the binary digits towards left 9 times and thereby shifting once in ch1[1] if we are treating *(ch1+2) as a single value (combining ch1[0], ch1[1], ch1[2]) ?

Comment: BTW, `*ch` is exactly equivalent to `ch[0]`. It refers only to the initial (zeroth) element of the array. And no, `*ch1<<9` absolutely does not refer to any other element of the array. The expression `*ch1<<9` computes a value using only the value of `*ch1` (and `9`) as input.

Comment: @user3633270 again, **no**. that isn't how the language works. There are plenty of people that have had to author big-number libraries in the past that certainly wish it *did* (optionally) work that way, but it *doesn't*. `*(ch+2)` results in the *value* of the `char` at `ch[2]`. The array has *nothing* to do with the impending shift operation forthcoming after that. The language doesn't do what you're expecting.

Comment: WhozCraig that's what I really had in my mind. if I can create an array of a hundred bytes I would have a REALLY BIG number stored and used for arithmetic operations. Now as you said - I understand that the language does not work that way.

Comment: @user3633270 actually it can work that way, but you need a BigInt library...

Comment: @user3633270 Thankfully there are such libraries already in existence, and you need not reinvent the wheel. Google, Gimp, OpenSSL (libcrypto), etc, all have their flavors. I use the `BN` (bignum) implementation from OpenSSL on a variety of projects and it meets my needs (usually). Yours may be different. Do some homework. Try some libs and see what works for you.

Comment: No; I was not trying to reinvent the wheel. I thought that the c language already had a wheel!

Comment: @user3633270 I could tell, no worries. Python, Perl, etc does seem to have a few edges on some things vs. C/C++ sometimes. Anyway, best of luck =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the pointer is **important** `ch1` is similar to a pointer to char- `char*`. when you do `*ch1` you are refering to the **char** that `ch1` is pointing at. if you want to treat the entire array as a number you need to cast it into an integer, which is also problematic because your array has 3 bytes, and an integer has 4, so the top byte of `x`  in the example below is pointing at, is actually **undefined**

```
int main()
{
    char ch1[3];
    ch1[0]=ch1[1] = 0;
    ch1[2]=0x01;
    int *x = (int*)ch1;
    *x <<= 2;
    printf("%u", ch1[2]);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks; +1 for your answer once I reach reputation 15.